# Django queryset filter trouble of manytomany field

Tags: django, model, django-queryset

I have a `ManyToMany` field, say `tags` of model `Article`. Now there's a query to select all `Article` whose `tags` contains X1 and X2 and X3 ... where X1, X2, X3... are `Tag` objects. How can I do this to gain a queryset with final results?

More formally:

```
class Tag(models.Model) {
    ...
}
class Article(models.Model) {
    tags = models.ManytoManyField(Tag)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are looking for *all* tags for a specific article, You can use [the `Q` filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects) and then chain the `Q`s

```
tags = ['X1', 'X2', 'X3']
qs = [Q(tags__name=tag.name) for tag in tags]

query = qs.pop() #get the first element

for q in qs:
    query &= q

articles = Article.objects.filter(query)
```

Comment: Wow, class Q is so powerful! And it fits my need perfectly. Thanks